# Why is magnetic flux proportional to the current?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

I know [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/410061/why-is-the-magnetic-flux-proportional-to-the-current-inductance) answer, but it does not answer my question. I want to know why is this proportionality, where does it come from. How can I derive it? To put it differently, I want to know where the

$$U=L\frac{dI}{dt}$$
comes from. If I know why flux is proportional to current, I know how to derive it.

EDIT:

Is is true that it is only proportional to current, if the current is constant across the surface/length? Not constant in time. If so, than I can see it following from the equation for the magnetic field; as the integral over the surface, for computing the flux would be linear in current (at a particular moment in time). I hope I worded this correctly.

Comment: Biot-Savart Law. Or you can confirm experimentally.

Comment: If the current is constant over space but not time you can still bring it out of the integral in the BSL. So this just means the field will also vary with time, but still be proportional to the current at any instant in time.

Comment: @AaronStevens Perhaps my wording was off. My question was, "Does it need to be contant over space?". Sorry for the confusion. I think yes? And thank you :)

Comment: Yes you are right. This is because if the current is not uniform in space, then you can't really define a single current that the field will be proportional to anyway. Mathematically this is the same as saying you can't take the current out of the integral in the BSL.